# Counting the number of users in web App in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have modified my application to find out the number of users logged in a web application below is my piece of code..

the listener class

```
    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;


public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener
{
        private static int count;

        public static int getActiveSessions() {
            return count;
            }



        public SessionCounter()
        {
        }

//The "sessionCount" attribute which has been set in the servletContext should not be modified in any other part of the application. 
//Since we are using serveltContext in both the methods to modify the same variable, we have synchronized it for consistency.


        public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e)
        {
                count++;
                ServletContext sContext = e.getSession().getServletContext();
                synchronized (sContext)
                {
                        sContext.setAttribute("sessionCount", new Integer(count));
                }
        }

        public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e)
        {
                count--;
                ServletContext sContext = e.getSession().getServletContext();
                synchronized (sContext)
                {
                        sContext.setAttribute("sessionCount", new Integer(count));
                }
        }
}
```

and the main servlet is ..

```
package com.saral;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class First
 */
//@WebServlet("/First")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class);


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        logger.info("before---->");

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name=request.getParameter("txtName");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello,"+name);
        out.println("<br> this output is generated by a simple servlet.");
        out.println("Total Number of users logged in--->"+SessionCounter.getActiveSessions());
        out.close();


    }

}
```

and the web.xml is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstDemo</display-name>


  <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.saral.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/helloServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <listener>
  <listener-class>com.saral.SessionCounter</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

but I am getting the total number of users logged in as 0 , which is not perfect, please advise where I am wrong and how can I overcome from this.

Comment: Try reading from servletcontext

Comment: I would suggest increase the counter when the user logged in meaning in the login request handling servlet and set it in application context and in logout get the counter value from context and decrease it ....and you should pass this value as context-param to web app.

Comment: Hi user1538526, it has been long since this is posted. Did you find an answer. if so could you answer your question below for others good?

Comment: sessions != logins

Answer (score 0):

When a client request come to the Tomcat server and you don't call `request.getSession()`, then the Tomcat server stil creates a session automatically. After that, the method `sessionCreated(...)` in your SessionCounter class is called.

The method `sessionDestroyed(...)` will be called when a session is destroyed. That occurs when you call `session.invalidate()`. If you close a tab on browser or close a browser, the session is still alive on your tomcat server.

I think so. You can use some diffrent listeners to archive your goal: `HttpSessionAttributeListener`, `HttpSessionBindingListener`,...